# Why is my navigation in my onepage not working?

Tags: menus, navigation, homepage, walker

I have a one-pager who has two sites. One is German and the other English.
I made an own navigation for the English one, but it doesn't work. The navigation is throwing me back to the German one.
The navigation should be like:
https://christoph-website.positioning-marketing.at/home-english/#about

But it goes back to the /#about from the German site.

I think the NavWalker is the problem.
Please help!

This is my navigation and my nav walker

```
                <div class="main-nav-wrapper">
                    <?php 
                    if ( is_page_template( 'page-home-english.php' ) ) {
                  wp_nav_menu(array(
                        'theme_location'    => 'english-navigation',
                        'container'         => 'nav',
                        'container_class'   => 'nav--main',
                        'menu_class'        => 'list list--nav mb0',
                        'menu_id'           => '42',
                      'walker'            => new MainNavWalker()
                    )); 
                        
                    }
                    else{
                        wp_nav_menu(array(
                        'theme_location'    => 'main_nav',
                        'container'         => 'nav',
                        'container_class'   => 'nav--main',
                        'menu_class'        => 'list list--nav mb0',
                        'walker'            => new MainNavWalker()
                    )); 
                    }
                    
                    ?>

                </div>

//Nav Walker 

<?php

class MainNavWalker extends Walker {

        var $db_fields = array(
                'parent' => 'menu_item_parent',
                'id'     => 'db_id'
        );



    function start_el( &$output, $item, $depth = 0, $args = array(), $id = 0 ) {

        $classes = empty ( $item->classes ) ? array () : (array) $item->classes;
        $class_names = join(' ', apply_filters('nav_menu_css_class', array_filter( $classes ), $item));
        $title = apply_filters( 'the_title', $item->title, $item->ID );

        //Logo Home
        if($item->url == get_bloginfo("url")."/" || $item->url == get_bloginfo("url")) {
            $class_names .= " home";
            $url = "#home";
        }
        else {
            $url = "#".strtolower($title);
        }

        if(!empty($class_names)){
            $class_names = ' class="menu__item '. esc_attr( $class_names ) . '"';
        }

        $attributes  = '';
        !empty( $item->attr_title )
                and $attributes .= ' title="'  . esc_attr( $item->attr_title ) .'"';
        !empty( $item->target )
                and $attributes .= ' target="' . esc_attr( $item->target     ) .'"';
        !empty( $item->xfn )
                and $attributes .= ' rel="'    . esc_attr( $item->xfn        ) .'"';

        !empty( $item->url )
                and $attributes .= ' href="'   . get_bloginfo("url") . $url.'"';

        if($depth == 0){

            $output .= "<li ". $class_names . ">";

            $item_output = $args->before
                . "<a data-scroll class='menu__link fade' $attributes>"
                . $args->link_before
                . $title
                . '</a> '
                . $args->link_after
                . $args->after;

        }

        // Since $output is called by reference we don't need to return anything.
        $output .= apply_filters('walker_nav_menu_start_el', $item_output, $item, $depth, $args);
    }

    function end_el( &$output, $item, $depth = 0, $args = array() ) {
        $output .= '</li>';
    }

    function start_lvl( &$output, $depth = 0, $args = array() ) {
        $output .= '<div class="sub-menu-wrapper"><ul class="sub-menu page-wrapper">';

    }

    function end_lvl( &$output, $depth = 0, $args = array() ) {
        $output .= '</ul></div>';

    }
}
```

Comment: What are the actual links you're putting in when you edit the menu?

Comment: @jacob-peattie
/home-english/#about

and in the German version /#about